# how to pass a integer variable argument to the NSTimer calling function

Tags: swift, nstimer

I would like to pass an variable having a integer value into a function while NSTimer calls that function

```
func work()
{
    var x= 10
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "Disp", userInfo: x , repeats: false)
}

    func Disp(timer:NSTimer)
    {
       //access the x value
       print("\(x)")
    }
```

But the userinfo part takes only arguments of types objects(AnyObject?). Please some one help me. Also the variable x should not be declared globally as x is a local variable and its value is assigned during runtime dynamically inside a method for my original need.

This is my exact situation. Please help me friends. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the value in user info while calling the NSTimer,when your Disp function will be called you can get the value from timer user info

```
 func work()
    {
        var x = 10
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "Disp:", userInfo: x , repeats: false)
    }


    func Disp(timer:NSTimer)
    {
        //access the x value
        print("\(timer.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would also like to know that is there any way to cast that {timer.userinfo} into integer and store it to another variable??

Comment: Whenever i try " var x= timer.userinfo as Int " i get the no build errors but while running i get "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error.

Comment: Yes, you can  print("\(timer.userInfo?.integerValue)")

Comment: or the second option is  var x : Int = 10, when you are passing the value from NSTimer